# How to remove duplicate spaces in wordpress with PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi today I have a string that can come with duplicate spaces and strings currently I'm using the code below to clean up

```
<?php
$string = '    lorem ipsum dolor s            it amet content     ';
trim( $string );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the code below it clears the spaces on the sides and also removes line breaks

```
<?php
    function remove_space( $text ) {
        $text = preg_replace('/[\t\n\r\0\x0B]/', '', $text);
        $text = preg_replace('/([\s])\1+/', ' ', $text);
        $text = trim( $text );
        return $text;
    }

    $exemplo = ' Lorem ipsum dolor sit      amet quaqluer dado
    test content generates              alrel lrea   ';
    $new_string = remove_space( $exemplo );

    echo $new_string;
```